# Get id and a field value in EasyAutocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using easyAutocomplete plugin, I autocomplete an input field and take the selected value and display them on a dropdown .
What I want to do, is have a hidden field that would have the id of the value.

My JSON File returns something like this :

```
{ "name": "Emily"
  "id" :  1
  "jobData": [
     {
      "id":1
      "loc":"AL"
      },
     {
      "id":2  
       "loc":"BG"

      } 
   ]
```

Once  I select Emily from my users, my dropdown gets filled with Locations of her job.
How do I also save the Id of the location in a hidden field so that I can send it to my controller?

This is my JS function:

```
 function AutoCompleteS() {
  $("#basics").keyup(function(e) {
  this.query = e.target.value;
      var options = {
                url: function(query) {
                    return "/getUser/"+ query
                },

                getValue:"name"

                list: {

                       onClickEvent: function() {
                        var value = $("#basics").getSelectedItemData();
                        function toArray(value){
                            return value.loc;
                        }

                        var allLocations=value.jobData.map(toArray);

                        $.each(allLocations,function(i,p){
                            $('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
                        })


                        }
                    }

            };

      $('#basics').easyAutocomplete(options);

});
  }
```

How do I get and pass the id ?

EDIT:
html code:

```
     <label for="client1" class=" control-label">First Client</label> <input type="text" name="client" value="" class="form-control  input-lg " id="basics"/>
    <label for="sel1">Select location:</label>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="select" >
    <option></option>
    <input type="text" class="hidden" />
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easyAutocomplete issues:
Your code should be more like this (see [remote data source example](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-remote)) - i.e. you should only call `easyAutocomplete` once:

```
$("#basics").easyAutocomplete({
  url: function(query) {
    return "/getUser/" + query;
  },
  getValue: "name",
  list: {
    // ...
  }
});
```

HTML issues:
Move the `input` outside the `select`, and give them both names (so the values can be submitted to server):

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="select" name="location">
<option></option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="hidden" name="job-id" id="job-id">
```

To set the value of the hidden field when the select value changes, you need a change handler:

```
function updateSelect(jobData) {
  // Reset options:
  $("#select")
    .empty()
    .append(new Option());

  // Add locations:
  jobData.forEach(function(job) {
    $("#select").append(new Option(job.loc));
  });

  // Handle dropdown change:
  $("#select")
    .off("change")
    .on("change", function() {
      // Reset job id (needed when user selects blank option at top of dropdown)
      $("#job-id").val("");

      var selectedLocation = this.value;
      jobData.forEach(function(job) {
        if (job.loc === selectedLocation) {
          // Copy job id to hidden field:
          $("#job-id").val(job.id);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Call `updateSelect` from your easyAutocomplete onClickEvent handler:

```
onClickEvent: function() {
  var value = $("#basics").getSelectedItemData();
  updateSelect(value.jobData);
}
```

Comment: What I wanted is to post the locations in the dropdown, as I already do. But to also save the id of each location somewhere in a hidden field so that I can pass it to my controller.
I  edited and added the html!